# Neuroph Image Recognition and Android Error

Tags: android, image-recognition

i'm trying to create an image recognition app for android using Neuroph Framework an Eclipse but i keep getting this errors

(Using the 2.7 framework version)
03-26 17:05:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3107): FATAL EXCEPTION: dataLoader
03-26 17:05:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3107): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork
03-26 17:05:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3107):     at com.example.meuprojetoandroid1.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:49)
03-26 17:05:20.533: E/AndroidRuntime(3107):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

(Using the 2.6 framework version)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478): java.lang.StackOverflowError
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:298)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getReflectionField(ObjectStreamClass.java:190)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1091)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:649)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1137)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:455)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1369)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 17:05:44.299: E/AndroidRuntime(3478):     at java

On 2.6 it did work with the example 
http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/android_image_recognition_using_neuroph.htm

But when i use my trainer nnet it gives me that error...
I tried training several neural networks but keep getting that error...
I used the 2.7 and 2.6 Neuroph Studio for training the networks...

Sorry if this is repeated but i didnt find anything relevant on the answers too...

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, [To use Neuroph 2.7 you need Java 1.7, wont run on android currently](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/download.html)

Comment: Thanks, thats what i had in mind. But about the 2.6 there's any procedure to do on training the neural networks ? I mean to work properly without stackoverflows?

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs for 2.6](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/android_image_recognition_using_neuroph.htm),

Important notice: When you a load neural network in Android, you need to do it in a separate thread with increased stack size

`new Thread(null, loadDataRunnable, "networkLoader", 32000).start();`

or you will get a java.lang.StackOverflowError.